# #define a template method

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to add debug within a template function, however not looking at re-editing the whole code.

Would one be able to

```
    #define theFunction<T>(size) _theFunction<T>(size, __FILE__, __LINE__)
    
    template<class T>  T*  _theFunction(int size, string file, int line)
    {
        if (fails) {
            printf("theFunction failed called at line %i on %s ", line, file);
         }
     }
```

of course returns '<' unexpected in macro declaration. Are there some tricks to make that work?

Comment: Not an answer at this stage, but C++20 obviates this need for the preprocessor https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location

Comment: would it be ok if the macro is used like this instead `theFunction(T,size)` (eg `theFunction(int,size)` ) ?

Comment: it would technically work but still need to rewrite all the calling function @largest_prime_is_463035818. The idea was to have something transparent. However, might work with optional arguments.

Comment: ok, then it doesnt really help. Posted as answer anyhow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps (not tested):

```
struct TheFunctionHelper {
  std::string file;
  int line;
  template<typename T> 
  T* invoke(int size) {
    return _theFunction<T>(size, file, line);
  }
};

#define theFunction TheFunctionHelper{__FILE__, __LINE__}.invoke
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing macros it helps to use the compiler flag that lets you see the output after preprocessing. For gcc it is `-E` to see that this:

```
#define theFunction(T,size) _theFunction<T>(size, __FILE__, __LINE__)

theFunction(int,42);
```

Expands to:

```
_theFunction<int>(42, "./example.cpp", 5);
```

It looks a bit odd to pass `int` as parameter to `theFunction(int,42)`, but once you decided to use macros, things are odd ;).

Also note that, as mentioned in a comment, C++20 has [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location), which eliminates one of the last corners that do require the use of macros in C++.